# How to set the eval variable value from code behind

Tags: asp.net

```
<a href="/web-services/" rel='<%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(this, "Testing") %>' runat="server" id="banquet" class="tr_delay_hover color_light tt_uppercase"><%# DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(this, "Testing") %>


public string Testing { get { return "hello world!"; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `#` by `=`

```
<a href="/web-services/" rel='<%= DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(this, "Testing") %>' runat="server" id="banquet" class="tr_delay_hover color_light tt_uppercase"><%= DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(this, "Testing") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the anchor html element as you had `runat="server"` attribute set, use `InnerText`

```
banquet.InnerText = Testing;
```